# In angular when printing text that is too long is overwriting the text and not going to next line

Tags: html, css, angular

So I have the following code in html

```
<div class="equipment-utilization-chart" >
<ng-container *ngIf="data.healthRecco1 !== ''" >
      <div class="recommendations"> <p> 1. {{data.healthRecco1}}</p> </div>
      <div class="recommendations"><p> 2. {{data.healthRecco2}}</p></div>
      <div class="recommendations"><p>3. {{data.healthRecco3}}</p></div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Value in data.healthRecco2 is really long, so it doesn't word wrap but rewrites on the same line making the text not decipherable

The following is the code in the .scss file

```
.equipment-utilization-chart {
  left: rem(444);
  width: rem(682);
  height: rem(85);
  line-height: 0;

 .recommendations {
width: auto;
height: auto;
margin-top: 35px;
word-wrap : break-word;  }
```

}

What should I do to get the text to word wrap to the next line. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: here is an article on html word wrapping that might be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

Comment: Remove `line-height: 0;` from the CSS.

Comment: thankyou the line-height was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue appears to be due to your use of `line-height: 0;`. By setting it to zero you're telling the browser to write new lines without any distance between the previous. Hence you're seeing the new lines appear over the top of the previous ones.

There are some nifty 'hacks' you can do with zero'ing out line-height. In this situation though it seems like it might be the cause of your particular issue.

I hope this little codepen will help in explaining what's going on:

https://codepen.io/ojako/pen/rZRvpW

Answer (score 0):

Try using word-wrap and white-space, something of that in css, try console what does the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this css in your scss code.

```
 .recommendations {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion..I tried using break-word, it is wrapping the text, but the problem is it is writing on the first line and not writing on the second line...i.e it is wrapping on the first line itself and so is unreadable...i